# Sql query to return SUM and # of rows that match query

Tags: jquery, sql-server

Table UserData (UserID,  Sales,   Credits)

I need to return the SUM of sales, sum of credits and the # of rows returned for a given date range.

Is it possible in 1 query?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(*), SUM(Sales), SUM(Credits)
FROM UserData
WHERE TransactionDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also give names to the computed columns like this

```
   SELECT 
      COUNT(*) AS NumRows, SUM(Sales) AS SalesTotal, SUM(Credits) AS CreditsTotal
   FROM UserData
   WHERE TransactionDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
```